# Meta-Analytic plot metafor

Tags: r, plot, metafor

I am performing meta-regression using `metafor`package, with two fixed effect variables; one as a log transformed variable (logx)  and one as factor (y) variable, and two nested random intercept terms

`meta1<-rma.mv(B, SE^2, mods = ~ logx+as.factor(y), random = ~ cohort|Study, struct = "CS",  data=subset(meta), control=list(optimizer="optim", optmethod="SANN"))`

I want to show the predicted estimates (B) as a function of the predictor (logx) in the plot (with corresponding 95% confidence interval bounds)

Can you please assist me?

Here is an example from the package documentation, but somehow I cannot recover that.